# How to display charts in Spyder

Tags: python, python-2.7, plotly, spyder, plotly-python

Since November 2015, plotly is Open-Source and available for python. https://plot.ly/javascript/open-source-announcement/

When trying to do some plots offline, these work in iPython Notebook (version 4.0.4)
But if I try to run them in Spyder (version 2.3.8), i just get the following output:

```
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>
```

There's something wrong in my code or the iPython Terminal of Spyder still doesn't support this?

Here goes the example code (taken from https://www.reddit.com/r/IPython/comments/3tibc8/tip_on_how_to_run_plotly_examples_in_offline_mode/)

```
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, iplot
from plotly.graph_objs import *
init_notebook_mode()

trace0 = Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
    y=[10, 11, 12, 13],
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=[40, 60, 80, 100],
    )
)
data = [trace0]
layout = Layout(
    showlegend=False,
    height=600,
    width=600,
)

fig = dict( data=data, layout=layout )

iplot(fig)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

importing plot instead iplot (and changing the last line from iplot(fig) to plot(fig) resolved the problem, at least in python 3:

```
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode,  plot
from plotly.graph_objs import *
init_notebook_mode()

trace0 = Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
    y=[10, 11, 12, 13],
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=[40, 60, 80, 100],
    )
)
data = [trace0]
layout = Layout(
    showlegend=False,
    height=600,
    width=600,
)

fig = dict( data=data, layout=layout )

plot(fig)
```

But instead you could do the following, which is slightly easier:

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs
plotly.offline.plot({
"data": [
    plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(    x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
    y=[10, 11, 12, 13], mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=[40, 60, 80, 100]))],
"layout": plotly.graph_objs.Layout(showlegend=False,
    height=600,
    width=600,
)
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try it tom first thing in the morning. Have no PC available.

Comment: Thanks @Dominix. 
Both solutions work in python 2.70 as well.

Answer (score 57):

If you'd like to develop your plotly figures in Spyder, perhaps because of Spyders superb variable explorer, you can easily display a **non-interactive image** by just running `fig.show()`. Note that this is for newer versions of plotly where you don't have to worry about `iplot` and `plotly.offline`.

And if you'd like display your figure in the browser as a **fully interactive** version, just run:

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default='browser'
```

Now your figure will be displayed in your default browser.

To switch back to producing your figure in Spyder, just run:

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default='svg'
```

You can check other options too using `pio.renderers?`:

```
Renderers configuration
-----------------------
Default renderer: 'svg'
Available rendere <...> wser', 'firefox', 'chrome', 'chromium', 'iframe',
'iframe_connected', 'sphinx_gallery']
```

You'll find even more details [here](https://plot.ly/python/renderers/) under `Setting the default renderer`

Here's a detailed example

**Code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import plotly.io as pio
#pio.renderers.default = 'svg'
pio.renderers.default = 'browser'

x = ['Product A', 'Product B', 'Product C']
y = [20, 14, 23]

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(
            x=x, y=y,
            text=y,
            textposition='auto',
        )])
fig.show()
```

**Plot:**

[image]

**System info:**

```
Python 3.7.6
Spyder 3.3.1
Plotly 3.2.0
```

Comment: Defaulting the output to browser saved the day for me (using Spyder 5). Thank you!

Comment: @cgage1 Glad to hear it! Spyder and Plotly is a nice combo!

Comment: Using `pio.renderers.default='svg'` triggers `Image export using the "kaleido" engine requires the kaleido package`, but otherwise this is a very helpful answer.