# Plotting Candle Stick in Python

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, candlestick-chart

I am trying to plot a candle stick chart in python. Here is my code

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf

yf.pdr_override()
mcd = pdr.get_data_yahoo("MCD", start="2004-01-01", end="2005-07-31")
mcd_candle = go.Candlestick(x=mcd.index,open=mcd.Open,high=mcd.High,low=mcd.Low,close=mcd.Close)
data = [mcd_candle]
py.iplot(data, filename='Candle Stick')
```

This is the error I am getting

```
PlotlyError: Because you didn't supply a 'file_id' in the call, we're assuming you're trying to snag a figure from a url. You supplied the url, '', we expected it to start with 'https://plot.ly'.
```

Any idea how I can draw a Candle Stick Chart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem must be because you didn't provide the `username` and `api key` which you will get from the `https://plot.ly/settings/api` link. If you want to use `plotly online` to create this graph. First create an account, then get the `username` and `api key` and insert it in the below code.

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf
py.sign_in('<<username here>>', '<<api key here>>')
yf.pdr_override()
mcd = pdr.get_data_yahoo("MCD", start="2004-01-01", end="2005-07-31")
mcd_candle = go.Candlestick(x=mcd.index,open=mcd.Open,high=mcd.High,low=mcd.Low,close=mcd.Close)
data = [mcd_candle]
py.iplot(data, filename='Candle Stick')
```

There is another option of using `plotly offline` which does not need all this procedure, please find below the implementation code.

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import plotly.offline as py_offline
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf
py_offline.init_notebook_mode()

yf.pdr_override()
mcd = pdr.get_data_yahoo("MCD", start="2004-01-01", end="2005-07-31")
mcd_candle = go.Candlestick(x=mcd.index,open=mcd.Open,high=mcd.High,low=mcd.Low,close=mcd.Close)
data = [mcd_candle]
py_offline.iplot(data, filename='Candle Stick')
#for Spyder plotting use the below line instead
#py_offline.plot(data, filename='Candle Stick')
```

Please make sure to install the libraries `pandas_datareader` and `fix_yahoo_finance` using `pip`, if these libraries are not already present!

Comment: By implementing your offline method, my code is running but I don't see the graph output. The code runs without any error. I am using Anaconda - Spyder. Python 3.x

Comment: @DebdiptaMajumdar Sorry about that, you need to use `py_offline.plot` instead of `py_offline.iplot` when using spyder, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315726/visualize-plotly-charts-in-spyder)