# Do I have to use jupyter notebook to plot ohlc candlestick in plotly?

Tags: plotly

plotly GUI interface is very nice. Just a simple question, does it only support Jupyter Notebook (for python)?

Answer (score 0):

It is a Python package and so must work on every editor.

Comment: hmm, I wonder does it support terminal? The reference I can find on it web page only supports notebook

Comment: See here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315726/visualize-plotly-charts-in-spyder