# Plotly: Figure window doesn't appear using Spyder

Tags: python, plotly, spyder

I'm running the code below in `Spyder 4.1.1` but the window that should contain the visualization doesn't appear. I am new to plotly. Please help.

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16])
fig.show()
```

Comment: My environment: The graph was displayed correctly in jupiter lab(mac), is it not a problem on the Spyder side?

Comment: @Dean Did my suggestion work out for you?

Comment: @vestland yep it did, thanks.

Comment: @quantum_engineer, I managed to get a static plot in Spyder too (by installing the dependencies and specifying 'iframe' as the renderer)

Comment: @Dean Would you consider marking one of the suggestions as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 15):

To get you started quickly, you can set `'browser'` as your renderer and launch your plotly figures in your default web browser. To my knowledge, this is the best way to produce plotly figures from Spyder and obtain the full flexibility of plotly figures (subsetting, zooming, etc).

**Code:**

```
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.express as px
pio.renderers.default='browser'

fig = px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16])
fig.show()
```

**Figure in browser:**

[image]

For further details you could also check out the post [Plotly: How to display charts in Spyder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315726/plotly-how-to-display-charts-in-spyder/59944998#59944998)

Answer (score 9):

If you prefer to display in Spyder and not in your browser, you may need to install Orca.  In your Anaconda terminal, use:

```
conda install -c plotly plotly-orca
```

From there, you should be able to use your previous code.  Setting the default renderer explicitly could help, too:

```
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.express as px
pio.renderers.default = "svg"

fig = px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16])
fig.show()
```

Comment: *** As of plotly 4.9, orca [has been deprecated](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/) and replaced by the `kaleido` library, which can be installed as `pip install kaleido`.

Comment: Had same issue. The orca solution worked fine for me. However have just spotted the comment re kaleido so I will investigate that also. Thanks all.....

Answer (score 2):

For plotly plots to appear in Spyder, a static image renderer is used. For that you need to have the required [dependencies](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/) installed. This is detailed in the [plotly renderer page](https://plotly.com/python/renderers/).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to working with kaleido, currently, there is an issue with version 0.2.1. Need downgrade to kaleido 0.1.*. See https://github.com/plotly/Kaleido/issues/110

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33923978)