# Spyder 5 is showing plots for matplotlib but not for plotly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, spyder

The following code yields a graph.

```py
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly, plotly.express as px
arr = np.array(np.arange(stop=257, start=1).reshape(-1,4,4))
dfs = [pd.DataFrame(i, index=["row1", "row2", "row3", "row4"], columns=["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"])for i in arr]
plt.plot(dfs[1])
plt.show()
```

but the following does not

```py
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly, plotly.express as px
arr = np.array(np.arange(stop=257, start=1).reshape(-1,4,4))
dfs = [pd.DataFrame(i, index=["row1", "row2", "row3", "row4"], columns=["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"])for i in arr]
px.line(dfs[1],x=dfs[1].index, y="col1").show()
```

clarification: both codes show plots when run in terminal but I can only see plot from matplotlib when these codes are run in spyder (there spyder tab "plots" only contains plot from matplotlib).

Comment: See [answer to 'Plotly: Figure window doesn't appear using Spyder'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61078161/8508004) about maybe sending it to your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in your second code, you're calling [`plotly.express.line`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.line.html) to make a [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/) plot (which is *interactive*) and I don't think Spyder can handle that.

> Plotly's Python graphing library makes **interactive**,
> publication-quality graphs.

You have at least, three choices/workarounds:

Either **(1)** use Jupyter Notebook or Jupyterlab.

Or **(2)** in Spyder, make the plot *static* (*as well as your matplotlib plot*) by adding these two lines :

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default='svg'
```

[image]

Or **(3)**, always in Spyder, set your default Internet browser as the renderer :

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default='browser'
```

[image]