# Unable to generate plot using Plotly in Spyder IDE

Tags: python, plot, plotly, spyder

I am using Spyder IDE. I am trying to get my plots to show but they won't show for some reason. 
X and Y axes are values from 2 separate dataframes. 
Code is as below.

```
    import plotly.graph_objects as go

    fig = go.Figure()

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=AsthmaCases.DataValue, y=dfCombinedToPlot.CasesPer100kPop, mode='lines', name='Asthma'))
    fig.show()
```

What is wrong or am I wrong in expecting fig.show() to have displayed my plot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotly: How to display charts in Spyder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315726/plotly-how-to-display-charts-in-spyder)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working solution:

```
from plotly.offline import plot
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, 1], y=[2, 3], mode='lines', name='Asthma'))
plot(fig)
```

A related question is there: [Plotly: How to display charts in Spyder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315726/plotly-how-to-display-charts-in-spyder)