# No interactivity in plotly plots in Spyder 4

Tags: python, plotly, spyder

I have recently upgraded to Spyder 4.1.3 (up from Spyder 3.x) and have also consequently upgraded many packages along the way. Plots now show up in the dedicated plots pane (which is a nice addition to Spyder in general). However, now when I generate plots using plotly, there is no interactivity with the resultant plots whether inline or in the plots pane. This used to be there in Spyder 3.x. For example, running [the sample code from plotly](https://plotly.com/python/scatter-plots-on-maps/):

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")
fig = px.scatter_geo(df, locations="iso_alpha",
                     color="continent", # which column to use to set the color of markers
                     hover_name="country", # column added to hover information
                     size="pop", # size of markers
                     projection="natural earth")
fig.show()
```

The plot shows up in the plot pane but when I hover over it with the mouse nothing pops up. When I run the same code in Jupyter I do get the interactivity. Any ideas about how to get this functionality going in Spyder 4?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotly: How to display charts in Spyder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315726/plotly-how-to-display-charts-in-spyder)

Comment: That is not really the same problem (and that question is from 4 years ago long before Spyder 4 with the plot pane came out). The problem is that the figure is produced in the Spyder plot pane but when I hover my mouse over it, it is just a static image with none of the interactivity. that I would expect from a plot made using plotly.