# Plotly showing no output

Tags: python, plot, plotly

Recently I found a code [here](https://plotly.com/python/pca-visualization/) to visualize PCA using `plotly`. I copied exactly the entire code which is:

```
import plotly.express as px
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

df = px.data.iris()
X = df[['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width']]

pca = PCA(n_components=3)
components = pca.fit_transform(X)

total_var = pca.explained_variance_ratio_.sum() * 100

fig = px.scatter_3d(
    components, x=0, y=1, z=2, color=df['species'],
    title=f'Total Explained Variance: {total_var:.2f}%',
    labels={'0': 'PC 1', '1': 'PC 2', '2': 'PC 3'}
)
fig.show()
```

And I have nothing in the output i.e. there is no plot in the output. I have `pyplot` installed so I'm not quite sure why it's not working. Can I ask you for a hand where is a problem?

[image]

(As you can see on the image above compiler is ignores my plot call)

Comment: works perfectly well for me.  **plotly** 5.3.1

Comment: This is because you are running the code in a notebook. Check out the [doc](https://plotly.com/python/ipython-notebook-tutorial/#plotting-inline) for plotting inline, or run the script normally.

Comment: I'm running code in spyder, not in jupyter

Comment: Try `fig.write_html('fig.html', auto_open=True)` instead of `fig.show()`, this should render the plot in the browser automatically.

Comment: [Plotly: How to display charts in Spyder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315726/plotly-how-to-display-charts-in-spyder)