# Python Plotly Dash Program paused or hung with no errors

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am here writing my first question after I tried a ready-to-use code on my laptop on Python (`SPyder` IDE).  The link to the code is: `https://github.com/Coding-with-Adam/Dash-by-Plotly/blob/master/Other/Dash_Introduction/intro.py` and video is `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hSPmj7mK6ng&t=2s&ab_channel=CharmingData` This is first time I trying to run a dash program.

I just now installed the dash, restarted my IDE. I downloaded this dash code and input data file. I ran this code but I see no errors (I do see Warnings) in my kernel. However, it hung at the same place for very long (10 min) and did not move further. What could be wrong? It ran and gave output in 2s when the same code was executed by the owner in a youtube video.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: try typing `localhost:8050` into a browser

Comment: Dash is for websites, not visualization within an IDE, it uses plotly, which is for use within IDEs/jupyter etc

Comment: @Helios wow! it worked like a cham. Thanks a ton. I am thinking and trying all for past 2 hrs. You made my day. Thanks ton.

Comment: @Helios I am currently using plotly and was rendering 3d plots in browser. So, the Dash is websites. What is the difference? both are rendered in the HTML browser only. Am I correct?

Comment: @Helios one more question: when the youtuber ran this code (it is his code), the program  rendered the HTML browser directly and he did not enter this `localhost:8050`. Why me I have to type this? why he  did not type it?

Comment: I'm running in Jupyter, you can start using `app.run_server(mode="inline")` which runs it inline.  Not familiar with Spyder.  **dash** is far more than this,  but can be considered a hosting environment for **plotly** to enable event based - **callbacks**

Comment: @RobRaymond I tried it. I replaced `app.run_server(debug=True)` with `app.run_server(mode="inline")`. It gave the following error `    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)

TypeError: run_simple() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mode'`

Comment: Are you trying to run a website/server or just view a graph? If it is the latter then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315726/plotly-how-to-display-charts-in-spyder Maybe you can link the video? I do not know about rendering websites in spyder - yes dash is running a webserver locally on your machine that you are then connecting to with localhost:8050. There is a huge amount more going on under the hood than just plotting a graph

Comment: @Helios I update the question and here is the link: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hSPmj7mK6ng&t=2s&ab_channel=CharmingData` Things you are mentioning could be new to me. Please, don't mind, explain me in best possible way. I thought it renders it on the HTML browser that I have.  Just like I was doing with the `plotly`, did not thought `dash` is different than this.